# Up/Down mod 105 counter based on 74193

Tags: digital-logic, counter, quartus-ii

I'm assigned with creating up/down counter in quartus II, but I can't find a way to do it properly. In simulation it always ends in transient state, so I guess there are some metastability issues that I don't understand, but I spent long hours on it and couldn't make it work.

This is my base design, are there any obvious issues at this stage that I'm missing?

[image]

Then I tried to ensure that counter is cleared only when we count up (104->0) and when it counts down, given value is loaded when it underflows (0->104).
What do I need to do, to make it work correctly?

Comment: Why BO/ to LOAD/  This makes it metastable.  You need a synchronous input clock not a feedback loop.

Comment: Do you have any VHDL/Verilog knowledge? I'm guessing not, otherwise you'd have written it in VHDL/Verilog already. But it would be simple to implement as a synchronous logic circuit and that would make it stable. If all things were an option, it'd be a faster route to success.

Comment: Sorry, I have very little knowledge about VHDL, we barely scratched the surface,  EE is not something I typically do and in this task I can't write it in VHDL. How exactly can I make it synchronous?

Comment: Stop thinking about clearing the counter asynchronously and start thinking about loading it with 0. You decode logic will produce glitches which will mess up your counter if not used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamentally a bad approach for an FPGA design. FPGAs (and their design tools) are highly optimized to support synchronous logic, in which all of the FFs in a given module are clocked directly by a single common clock. Special techniques are used to transfer signals from one clock domain to another.

Although the 74193 is called a "synchronous counter", it is a very loose application of the term. If you look at the internal implementation in any data book, you'll see that every FF in it has a unique clock. And the "clear" and "load" functions are asynchronous, not synchronous. Duplicating the exact function of just one of these chips in an FPGA is going to be a messy proposition at best, and trying to build more complex circuits using them will be even worse.

If you must do this project using schematic entry rather than HDL, then you would be much better off using 7 separate FFs, an 8-bit register such as a 74374, or even a truly synchronous counter like the 74169.